# Control Arrays declared at Form Level

Tags: arrays, controls

```
Public Class Form1

    Public TextBoxArray() As TextBox = {Me.T1, Me.T2}

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        MsgBox(TextBoxArray(1).Text)

    End Sub

End Class
```

Why does this produce a Null reference error?

My controls are created at Design time and added to a Public array that needs to be accessed form other forms and modules.

if I declare the Array in a Module then it works, however the problem with declaring it in a module is that it loads the form when creating the array and that cannot happen. I don't want the form to load at the time the array is declared, I want it available after the form is loaded.

Comment: add tag of language which your use

Answer (score 0):

After many trial and error I found something that works perfect:

Public TextBoxArray As New List(Of TextBox)